# How to make marquee in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-router

I am new in react native , I want to scroll the image continuously top to bottom and vice-versa in react native.

We can scroll image in html using marquee tag.

```
 E.g.,
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">
       <img src="../t1.png"/>
    </marquee>
```

Similar thing I want to achieve in react native.

Is it possible in react native or not ? I don't know how.

Can any one guide me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use react native animated api. it is possible with it.
try this --- https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-animations-using-the-animated-api-ebe8e0669fae

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install dependency : npm install react-native-marquee-view --save

Then use view
import MarqueeView from 'react-native-marquee-view';

<MarqueeView
style={{
backgroundColor: 'blue',
width: 200,
}}>
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
This is demo content